# Is $X$ an algebraic subset? Analytic subset?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and that every (complex) hyperplane section of $X$ is an algebraic subset (respectively analytic subset) of complex dimension at least one (or empty). Is it then true that $X$ is an algebraic subset (respectively analytic subset)? Note that if every hyperplane section is a bunch of points, then nothing can be said, since any real $2$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{C}^n$ has this property.

Comment: ??  $\mathbb R^2$ is a real surface in $\mathbb C^2$; hyperplane sections like $z_1 = 0$ are NOT a bunch of points!